# Filtering out the data frame whose row dimension is zero in R

Tags: r, filter, while-loop, dimensions

I have many data frames like df1,df2,...,df11 whose dimensions are 20,3; 40,4,; 0,5;...0,2; these dimensions does not remain constant in my program from where I'm calculating my data frames.So I want to filter out those data frames who have zero row dimensions like dim(df3) gives 0,5
This is what I have tried

```
while(!dim(df(i))[1]==0)
 {

  DF=paste("df",c(1:11))

 }
```

Thanks

Comment: do you want the names of not null dataframes or you want the dataframes itself as a list?

Comment: @joel.wilson, want the dataframes itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `Filter` after keeping the datasets in a `list`

```
Filter(function(x) nrow(x)>1, mget(paste0("df", 1:11)))
```

Or another option is `sapply` to create a logical vector and then subset the `list`

```
lst <- mget(paste0("df", 1:11))
i1 <- sapply(lst, nrow)>0 
lst[i1]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just to explain where you could have gone wrong. You should have preferred a `for` instead `while`

If you want only the names of non-empty data.frames :

```
total_num_dataframes = 4
DF  =character(0)
for (i in 1:total_num_dataframes){
  if (dim(get(paste0("df",i)))[1] != 0) 
    DF = c(DF,paste0("df",i))

}
```

If you want the data.frames itself :

```
DF = vector('list', length = total_num_dataframes)
j = 1
for (i in 1:total_num_dataframes){
  if (dim(get(paste0("df",i)))[1] != 0) {
    DF[[j]] = get(paste0("df",i))
    j = j+1
  }

}
```